# How to seperate a list into table formate using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scraped data from a multiple table from the website into the list format and plz help me to separate lists into table format. I have tried split() but no use on it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

class ProductTracker:

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'}
        # self.responce = requests.get(url=self.url, headers= self.user_agent).text
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.responce = driver.page_source
        driver.close()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.responce, 'lxml')

    def product_header(self):
        # for tabletitle in self.soup.findAll('h3', attrs={'class': 'search-table-view__heading'}).text:
        tabletitles = self.soup.find_all('h3', {'class': 'search-table-view__heading'})
        table_titles_list = []
        for title in tabletitles:
            table_titles_list.append(title.text)
        return table_titles_list
        return "Tag Not Found"

    def product_tableheader(self):
        tableheaders = self.soup.find_all('th',
                                          class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("search-table-view__cell"))
        header_lst = []
        for tableheader in tableheaders:
            try:
                header_lst.append(tableheader.div.a.span.text.strip())
            except:
                try:
                    header_lst.append(tableheader.div.text.strip())
                except:
                    pass
        return header_lst
        return "Tag Not Found"

    def product_tablevalues(self):
        tablevalues = self.soup.find_all('tr', class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith(
            "search-table-view__web-parent-table-row"))
        values_lst = []
        for tablevalue in tablevalues:
            td_lst = tablevalue.find_all('td', class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith(
                "search-table-view__web-parent-table-row-cell"))
            for td in td_lst:
                try:
                    values_lst.append(td.text.strip().replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace("                                                   "," ").replace("                                           "," "))
                except:
                    pass
        return values_lst
        return "Tag Not Found"
material = ProductTracker(url = "https://www.grainger.com/category/power-transmission/bearings/ball-bearings/radial-ball-bearings")
print(material.product_header())
print(material.product_tableheader())
print(material.product_tablevalues())
```

Below is my outPut and I have removed some data from the OutPut:

```
['NTN Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'BL Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series', 'BL Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Inch Series', 'DAYTON Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series',........'TORRINGTON BEARINGS Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series']
['Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price', 'Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price', 'Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price']
['4 mm', '13 mm', '5 mm', 'Double Shielded', '5U557', 'Regular Price $15.22 / each', '5 mm', '16 mm', '5 mm', 'Double Shielded', '5U592', 'Regular Price $10.10 / each', '6 mm', '19 mm', '6 mm', 'Select Seal/Shield Type', 'Multiple Items', '$9.10 - $14.65', '7 mm', '19 mm', '6 mm', 'Select Seal/Shield Type', 'Multiple Items', '$5.75 - $9.90', '7 mm', '22 mm', '7 mm', 'Select Seal/Shield Type', 'Multiple Items', '$8.50 - $15.05', '8 mm', '22 mm', '7 mm', 'Select Seal/Shield Type', 'Multiple Items', '$8.15, '9 mm', '24 mm', '7 mm', 'Double Shielded', '5U530', 'Regular Price $8.65 / each', '0.4375 in', '1.125 in', .............'0.375 in', 'Select Seal/Shield Type', 'Multiple Items', '$13.25 - $13.85', '0.4375 in', '0.9062 in', '0.3125 in', 'Select Seal/Shield Type', 'Multiple Items', '$11.25 - $11.80']
```

I have to split my list and change like a table for example:

```
['NTN Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series']

['Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price']
['4 mm','3 mm','5 mm','Double Shielded','5U557','Regular Price$15.22 / each']
['5 mm','16 mm','5 mm','Double Shielded','5U592','Regular Price$10.10 / each']

['BL Single Row Radial Ball Bearings, Metric Series']

['Bore Dia.', 'Outside Dia.', 'Width', 'Seal/Shield Type', 'Item #', 'Price']
['10 mm','15 mm','12 mm','Double Shielded','5U559','Regular Price$16.22 / each']
['54 mm','21 mm','9 mm','Double Shielded','5U598','Regular Price$10.10 / each']
```

Comment: the bottom isn't a table. Please show the desired output as an actual table and include the url if possible, otherwise the relevant html.

Comment: @QHarr I require output which I gave in the example I tried a lot but can't separate it the link is https://www.grainger.com/category/power-transmission/bearings/ball-bearings/radial-ball-bearings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

for section in soup.select('.search-table-view__web-parent'):
    title = [section.select_one('.search-table-view__heading').text]
    header_row = [i.text.strip() for i in section.select_one(' .search-table-view__web-parent-table-head-row').select('th')][:-1]

    print(title)
    print()
    print(header_row)

    for row in section.select('.search-table-view__web-parent-table-row'):
        print([re.sub('\n+|\s{2,}',' ',r.text.strip()) for r in row.select('td')][:-1])
    
    print()
```

As you need to loop sections perhaps a re-write to include a call which allows for this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time, re

class ProductTracker:

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.user_agent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'}
        # self.responce = requests.get(url=self.url, headers= self.user_agent).text
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.response = driver.page_source
        driver.close()
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.response, 'lxml')
    
    def loop_sections(self):
        try:
            for section in self.soup.select('.search-table-view__web-parent'):
                print(self.product_header(section))
                print()
                print(self.product_tableheader(section))
                self.product_tablevalues(section) # you might change this from a list of lists to print during as loop rather than nested list comprehension
                print()
        except Exception as e:
            print("error", e)
            return
        
    def product_header(self, section):
        try:
            table_title = [section.select_one('.search-table-view__heading').text]
            return table_title
        except Exception as e:
            print("error", e)
            return

    def product_tableheader(self, section):
        try:
            tableheaders = [i.text.strip() for i in section.select_one(' .search-table-view__web-parent-table-head-row').select('th')][:-1]
            return tableheaders
        except Exception as e:
            print("error", e)
            return
    
    def product_tablevalues(self, section):
        try:
            for row in section.select('.search-table-view__web-parent-table-row'):
                print([re.sub('\n+|\s{2,}',' ',r.text.strip()) for r in row.select('td')][:-1])
            return
        except Exception as e:
            print("error", e)
            return
        
material = ProductTracker(url = "https://www.grainger.com/category/power-transmission/bearings/ball-bearings/radial-ball-bearings")
material.loop_sections()
```

Comment: sorry Mr.QHarr, your output is different from my example output

Comment: Could you plz help me to get my example output

Comment: Is revision closer to requirement?

Comment: I tried to write this output to excel but getting an attribute error could you help me plz...

Comment: Hiiya, feel free to open a new question. Sorry I didn't see this comment before now.